# How to center vertically and horizontally table using css flexbox?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm trying to center table vertically and horizontally via `flexbox`.

One "screen" - one table in the middle, scrolling, - yet another table in the middle.

But via this code doesn't work:

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

table {
  text-align : center;
}

thead {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : forestgreen;
}

tfoot {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : tomato;
}

th, td {
  width : 5vw;
}

body {
  min-height : 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height : 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tj>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div><!-- wrapper end -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tj>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  <div><!-- wrapper end -->
</body>
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If to have the `table`'s each centered per full screen/viewport, to scroll between the 2 tables, check sample 1 below, where I moved all properties from the `body` rule to the `.wrapper` rule.

If you intended to have the 2 `table`'s on top of each other, check sample 2 below, which have `flex-direction: column` set.

To center the `table`'s side-by-side, remove `min-height: 100vh` from the `wrapper` rule, sample 3.

---

Sample 1 - one per full screen/viewport

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

table {
  text-align : center;
}

thead {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : forestgreen;
}

tfoot {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : tomato;
}

th, td {
  width : 5vw;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height : 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div><!-- wrapper end -->

  <div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div><!-- wrapper end -->
```

---

Sample 2 - on top of each other

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

table {
  text-align : center;
}

thead {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : forestgreen;
}

tfoot {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : tomato;
}

th, td {
  width : 5vw;
}

body {
  min-height : 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div><!-- wrapper end -->

  <div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div><!-- wrapper end -->
```

---

Sample 3 - side-by-side

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
}

table {
  text-align : center;
}

thead {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : forestgreen;
}

tfoot {
  font-weight : bold;
  background : tomato;
}

th, td {
  width : 5vw;
}

body {
  min-height : 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tj>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div><!-- wrapper end -->

  <div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tj>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>1</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div><!-- wrapper end -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but, why using `flexbox` in `body` and `.wrapper` differs?

Comment: @LexUshakov Because `display: flex` only work one level down, so in your case the `wrapper`'s became flex row items, not the `table`'s. If you add a border to the `wrapper` in your original code, you'll see how they render and likely also understand why

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `place-content: center` with `display: grid` to achieve this.

### What's `place-content` ?

> From [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/place-content/)
>
> The place-content property in CSS is shorthand for the align-content
> and justify-content properties, combining them into a single
> declaration in CSS Grid and Flexbox layouts, where align-content and
> justify-content are values that align an individual item in the block
> and inline directions.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  place-content:center;
}
th, td {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead style="background:forestgreen">
        <tj>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>1</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

      <tfoot style="background:tomato">
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```